If a Finite Abelian $p$-Group $G$ Has a Unique Subgroup of Order $p$, then $G$ is Cyclic (Specific Proof)
I seek to finish the following proof of the proposition from the title:
Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group, where $p$ is prime. If $G$ has exactly one subgroup $H$ of order $p$, then $G$ is cyclic.
Proof: We proceed by induction on $|G|$. If $|G| = p$, then $G$ is cyclic and we are done. If $|G| > p$, then define a group homomorphism $\phi: G \to G$  by $g \mapsto g^p$. Evidently $\ker \phi = H$ since $\ker \phi$ is the set of elements in $G$ with order at most $p$. This means that $\ker \phi$ is nontrivial, so that $|\phi(G)| < |G|$. Note that $\phi(G)$ is nontrivial (if trivial, then $\{e\} \simeq G/H$, so that $G \simeq H$, so that $|G| = p$). Hence we may apply the induction hypothesis to see that $\phi(G)$ has a generator $g$. Note that $\phi(G) = \langle g \rangle$ has exactly one subgroup of order $p$ since it is a nontrivial cyclic $p$-group, so that $H \leq \langle g \rangle$ by the given uniqueness assumption.
I am not sure where to go from here, but it seems I should be done quite quickly.
I am aware that there are other proofs of this result on MSE, but I would like to salvage this one if possible.

Working through your proof, trying to distinguish $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$ and $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$.  For $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$ I seem to run into trouble at "Note that $\phi(G)$ is nontrivial (if trivial, ..., $|G| = p$)" because $\phi((\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2) = {e}$ but $|(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2| \neq 2$.
